# git log output like svn ls -v

Tags: svn, git

Is there a way to make git give me output like svn ls -v does.  Basically a list of each file and who last edited that file?  Like this:

```
filea.txt     Someone Else
fileb.txt     Another Person
```

Maybe even with the SHA to identify the commit the change happened in?

Comment: thats tight, i didnt know about svn ls for some reason, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a very natural question to ask in git, but you can probably achieve something like what you want with something like this.

```
for a in $(ls); do git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09$a" -1 -- "$a"; done
```

This goes through each file in the current directory and performs a `git log` on it to find the last commit to have affected it.

It's not very efficient, as it searches the git history for each file and makes no effort to reuse the results of previous searches. It is, however, a one-liner.

Comment: Also added --no-pager and another echo to get a new line.

for a in $(ls); do git --no-pager log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09$a" -1 -- "$a"; echo "" ; done

Comment: @koppor The full list is on the man page for git-log, under the PRETTY FORMATS section and the format:<string> listing: [git-log man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

Comment: Man, I wish the man pages had actual examples of how to use all those lovely flags. :|

Answer (score 7):

You want to play around with [git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) and its pretty formats. Here's an example that doesn't completely address what you want, but should get you on the way:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h: %s -- %an"
```

Prints:

```
...
58a2e46: Added readme for github. -- DylanFM
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is: why do you need it? Currently git lacks single command that would do "svn ls -v" equivalent, and you would have to do a bit of scripting: the "git log -1 -- $filename" idea is, I think, the simplest solution (in term of number of lines of script to write); if it would, it probably will be as "git blame ".

But I guess that there is alternate way to solve your issue that you used "svn ls -v" to solve.

Please also remember that with nonlinear history the notion who last changed file is not unambiguous.

Comment: I only needed it in one particular, weird case.  I was removing kruft from previous versions of a website after two other people re-designed it.  Anything that was added by me was from the old site, anything from them was new.

Day to day, you're right, I wouldn't need it.

Comment: Oh and in this case, I knew the history was linear... all my changes stopped at least a month before anyone else touched it.

Comment: Wouldn't "git log -p --author=<name>" be a good alternate solution for this issue?

Comment: So you want to know all the files they changed. I think '--author=<name>' (or '--after=<date>', or <rev>.. specifier) combined with '--names-only' and appropriate '--pretty=format=...' option, and sort and uniq, can be used to generate list of all files changed by them.