# The shortest possible output from git log containing author and date

Tags: git, formatting, logging

How can I show a git log output with (at least) this information:

```
* author
* commit date
* change
```

I want it compressed to one line per log entry. What's the shortest possible format for that?

(tried `--format=oneline` but that does not show the date)

Comment: Maybe you like my colored version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49534733/2292766

Comment: Colored git history using git alias: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63145145/7881859.

Answer (score 1124, accepted):

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"
```

does the job. This outputs:

```
  fbc3503 mads    Thu Dec 4 07:43:27 2008 +0000   show mobile if phone is null...   
  ec36490 jesper  Wed Nov 26 05:41:37 2008 +0000  Cleanup after [942]: Using timezon
  ae62afd tobias  Tue Nov 25 21:42:55 2008 +0000  Fixed #67 by adding time zone supp
  164be7e mads    Tue Nov 25 19:56:43 2008 +0000  fixed tests, and a 'unending appoi
  93f1526 jesper  Tue Nov 25 09:45:56 2008 +0000  adding time.ZONE.now as time zone 
  2f0f8c1 tobias  Tue Nov 25 03:07:02 2008 +0000  Timezone configured in environment
  a33c1dc jesper  Tue Nov 25 01:26:18 2008 +0000  updated to most recent will_pagina
```

Inspired by [stackoverflow question: "git log output like svn ls -v"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468106/git-log-output-like-svn-ls-v/469238#469238), I found out that I could add the exact params I needed.

To shorten the date (not showing the time) use `--date=short`

In case you were curious what the different options were:
`%h` = abbreviated commit hash
`%x09` = tab (character for code 9)
`%an` = author name
`%ad` = author date (format respects --date= option)
`%s` = subject
From [kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) (PRETTY FORMATS section) by comment of Vivek.

Comment: ... and it is also useful to add `date=short` like cdunn2001 suggests in another answer

Comment: My favorite (short) oneliner is now to swap date before author and use the short date: `git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad%x09%an%x09%s" --date=short`

Comment: Spice it up with color and also show refs: `git log --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an%Cgreen%d %Creset%s' --date=short`

Comment: @kynan nice touch with the colors:) Although i find them a little too bright for the purpose

Comment: Fixed width columns table: `alias glop="git log --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h|%Cred%ad|%Cblue%an|%Cgreen%d %Creset%s' --date=short | column -ts'|' | less -r"`

Comment: both Jesper and Ciro's solution, cannot align different length of author name, same result. use Jesper's as it's simpler.

Comment: @liuyang1 Here's a way of formatting the name to some reasonable fixed number of characters, say 30, using 'awk' instead of 'columns': alias glop="git log --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h|%Cred%ad|%Cblue%an|%Cgreen%d %Creset%s' --date=short|awk -F'|' '{printf \"%s %s %-30s %s\n\", \$1,\$2,\$3,\$4}'"

Comment: @liuyang1You dont need to cal `awk`, since git log formatter has `trunc` for truncation. Ask a new question not to sidetrack this question further

Comment: In case you were curious what the different options were: 
%h =  abbreviated commit hash,
%x09 = tab (character for code 9),
%an = author name,
%ad = author date (format respects --date= option),
%s  = subject. From https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html (PRETTY FORMATS section)

Comment: this is too easy to remember make it more complex

Comment: use an alias @MuhammadUmer

Comment: I'm basically doing what is done here, but outputting to a file (without colours). How would I get each commit to show on its own line? `git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad %an%d %s' --date=short > file.txt`

Comment: Thanks. I find it pleasing to have the date column first before username for better alignment

Comment: You may want to try `%C(auto)` in the format string. I would also suggest using `tformat` instead of `format` or the end of the last line is probably incorrect (= missing linefeed). Note that if you skip the `format:` prefix, `tformat:` is assumed.

Comment: Use `--date=iso` for YYYY-MM-DD dates; and `--date=relative` for `5 days ago` dates.

Comment: git log --pretty=format:"%h  %an %x09 %ad %x09 %s" --date=short

Comment: Note that the official documentation for this answer can be found in `man git log`, then search for `%h` by typing `/%h` and pressing Enter. This will quickly jump you down to the `format:<string>` section of the man pages, which lists out all of these `%` options for the format string.

Comment: If you like @kynan's colors and @Ciro's columns, but found that  `columns` is removing the colours, then you can use the pretty-format `%<(N)` [column formatting](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emltltNgttruncltruncmtruncem) (in 1.8.3 or newer) instead of `columns`. E.g. `git log -S analytics --abbrev-commit --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h  %Cred%ad  %Cblue%<(20)%an  %Cgreen%d %Creset%s' --date=short`. _(Note: this causes characters with accents, like Š, to take up an extra space, at least in my terminal, but the output still looks great for me)_

Comment: Why is the SHA so short?

Comment: `alias gl="git log --pretty=format:'%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s'"`

Comment: if you want comparable dates then add `--date=format-local:%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S`. And since commiter names may contain spaces, it's more convenient to put the date first: `--pretty=format:"%h%x09%ad%x09%an%x09%s"`

Comment: Is there a way to use this along with --author="[me]" and a date range? If I add --author to this, it errors out. Thanks :)

Comment: If you like @kynan's colors but want date in dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss (without timezone), use this alias: `git config --global alias.hs “log --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an%Cgreen%d %Creset%s' --date=format:%d/%m/%y\ %H:%M:%S”`. Then use `git hs` (hs short for history).

Answer (score 270):

I use these two .gitconfig settings:

```
[log]
  date = relative
[format]
  pretty = format:%h %Cblue%ad%Creset %ae %Cgreen%s%Creset
```

%ad is the author date, which can be overidden by `--date` or the option specified in the [log] stanza in .gitconfig.
I like the relative date because it gives an immediate feeling of when stuff was comitted.
Output looks like this:

```
6c3e1a2 2 hours ago you@me.com lsof is a dependency now.
0754f18 11 hours ago you@me.com Properly unmount, so detaching works.
336a3ac 13 hours ago you@me.com Show ami registration command if auto register fails
be2ad45 17 hours ago you@me.com Fixes #6. Sao Paolo region is included as well.
5aed68e 17 hours ago you@me.com Shorten while loops
```

This is all of course in color, so it is easy to distinguish the various parts of a log line.
Also it is the default when typing `git log` because of the [format] section.

2014 UPDATE:
Since git now supports padding I have a nice amendment to the version above:

```
pretty = format:%C(yellow)%h %Cblue%>(12)%ad %Cgreen%<(7)%aN%Cred%d %Creset%s
```

This right aligns the relative dates and left aligns committer names, meaning you get a column-like look that is easy on the eyes.

**Screenshot**

[image: ss#1]

2016 UPDATE: Since GPG commit signing is becoming a thing, I thought I'd update this post with a version that includes signature verification (in the screenshot it's the magenta letter right after the commit). A short explanation of the flag:

> %G?: show "G" for a good (valid) signature, "B" for a bad signature, "U" for a good signature with unknown validity and "N" for no signature

Other changes include:

- colors are now removed if the output is to something other than the tty (which is useful for grepping etc.)
- `git log -g` now contains the reflog selector.
- Save 2 parens on refnames and put them at the end (to preserve column alignment)
- Truncate relative dates if they are too long (e.g. `3 years, 4..`)
- Truncate commiter names (might be a little short for some ppl, just change the `%<(7,trunc)` or check out the [git .mailmap feature](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog) to shorten commiter names)

Here's the config:

```
pretty = format:%C(auto,yellow)%h%C(auto,magenta)% G? %C(auto,blue)%>(12,trunc)%ad %C(auto,green)%<(7,trunc)%aN%C(auto,reset)%s%C(auto,red)% gD% D
```

All in all column alignment is now preserved a lot better at the expense of some (hopefully) useless characters.
Feel free to edit if you have any improvements, I'd love to make the message color depend on whether a commit is signed, but it doesn't seem like that is possible atm.

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot of git log]

Comment: You can shorten the lines even more by using a [mailmap](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shortlog.html#_mapping_authors). I have abbreviated the names of colleagues at my workplace down to only their first name :-)

Comment: The --pretty format answers are good, and the `tig` answer gives interactivity with no required configuration, but this one is brilliant -- it gives the requested one-line output (with color to boot!) using the standard 'git log' command. Very nice.

Comment: When using --right-left, I don't get the `>` `<` marks anymore. Tried adding `%m` to the format, but then `>` appears every time, even for a normal `git log`. Any clues how to have marks behave normally with the format?

Comment: +1 for stating that `ad` respects the `--date` option and permanently storing a default in gitconfig. I used `ar` before and had no easy way for switching between formats, when I needed an exact timestamp

Comment: I'm having a hard time configuring my `.gitconfig`, even with your snippets I'm not sure in what sections to put them and how to use them. I've tried a few times to no result. can you post your `.gitconfig` file?

Comment: @AlvaroCavalcanti sure no problem! https://gist.github.com/andsens/3ba598d829e948e1bf816e2c4cd5f282

Comment: @andsens Do you know how to only apply the gitconfig's pretty format to command with --oneline, but leave "git log" alone?

Comment: @TrầnViệtHoàng `--oneline` is just an alias for `--pretty=oneline`. `format.pretty` is the default pretty format, but there is no way to override `format.oneline` afaik. What I'd do is omit the `pretty = shortlog` line in the config and then make an alias for running `git log --pretty=shortlog`.

Answer (score 151):

Feel free to use this one:

```
git log --pretty="%C(Yellow)%h  %C(reset)%ad (%C(Green)%cr%C(reset))%x09 %C(Cyan)%an: %C(reset)%s" --date=short -7
```

Note the `-7` at the end, to show only the last 7 entries.

Look:

[image]

Comment: `--date=short` can be added to make it shorter.

Comment: @Hannes, Where are the branch names?

Comment: @Pacerier `git log` always shows the history of the currently checked out branch.

Comment: Add `%d` to restore "ref names" like `(HEAD -> master)`.

Comment: Why use `reset` instead of `auto`?

Comment: That's the good stuff here
`git log --pretty="%C(reset)%ad %C(Cyan)%an %C(reset)%s" --date=short`

Comes like this
`YYYY-MM-DD Author Commit_Message`

Answer (score 129):

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H %an %ad"
```

use `--date=` to set a date format

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H %an %ad" --date=short
```

Comment: Great! Next time I'll probably only use %h over %H as the hash is just nonsense for my human eyes:)

Comment: Cool! I was not aware of --date=short

Comment: Just throwing this out there (8 years late): the hash may look like nonsense, but it's a useful tool if you wanted to cherrypick or compare the commits. Often you list the hash not because it has meaning, but because it has **use**

Comment: @stevendesu I suspect the point @JesperRønn-Jensen was making is that the long hash (`%H`) is overly verbose compared to the short hash (`%h`).  Note that the short hash can be used for anything the long hash can be used for (including e.g. cherrypicking/comparing), assuming no collisions in the short hash.

Answer (score 114):

[image]
<sub>The `-10` at the end is to show the last 10 commits.</sub>

Use predefined git alias (`hs` - short for history):

```bash
git hs
```

Created once by command:

```bash
git config --global alias.hs "log --pretty='%C(yellow)%h %C(cyan)%cd %Cblue%aN%C(auto)%d %Creset%s' --graph --date=relative --date-order"
```

`%h` = abbreviated commit hash
`%cd` = committer date (*format respects `--date=` option*)
`%aN` = author name (*respects [`.mailmap`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmailmap)*)
`%d` = ref names
`%s` = subject

P.S. Since Git v2.13.0, `--decorate` is enabled by default.

References:

- [Git - git-log Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)
- [Difference between author and committer in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750808/difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git)
- [How GitHub uses the Git author date and commit date](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/troubleshooting-commits-on-your-timeline#how-github-uses-the-git-author-date-and-commit-date)

Comment: This was so helpful! Thanks! I like this adjustment: `git log --pretty='%C(cyan)%ad %C(yellow)%h %C(cyan)%d %Creset%s' --date-order --graph --date=iso`

Comment: I also like `git log --pretty='%C(cyan)%ad %C(yellow)%h %C(cyan)%d %Creset%s %C(red)%aN' --date-order --graph --date=iso` for when I care about author name.

Comment: @Ryan I very liked your last adjustment! do you know if it's possible to save the 6 characters wasted in each line on the timezone?

Comment: @elady See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7651644/7881859).

Comment: Thanks @WenfangDu! this is working for me: `git log --pretty='%C(cyan)%ad %C(yellow)%h %C(cyan)%d %Creset%s %C(red)%aN' --date-order --graph --date=format:%d/%m/%y\ %H:%M:%S`

Comment: How did you create the wonderful (transparent, rounded) console screenshot ?

Comment: @hc_dev iShot Pro

Answer (score 60):

**tig** is a possible alternative to using the **git log** command, available on the major open source *nix distributions.

On **debian or ubuntu** try installing and running as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tig
```

For mac users, brew to the rescue :

```
$ brew install tig
```

(tig gets installed)

```
$ tig
```

(log is displayed in pager as follows, with current commit's hash displayed at the bottom)

```
2010-03-17 01:07 ndesigner      changes to sponsors list
2010-03-17 00:19 rcoder         Raise 404 when an invalid year is specified.
2010-03-17 00:06 rcoder         Sponsors page now shows sponsors' level.
-------------------------- skip some lines ---------------------------------
[main] 531f35e925f53adeb2146dcfc9c6a6ef24e93619 - commit 1 of 32 (100%)
```

Since markdown doesn't support text coloring, imagine: column 1: blue; column 2: green; column 3: default text color. Last line, highlighted. Hit **Q** or **q** to exit.

---

`tig` justifies the columns **without ragged edges**, which an ascii tab (%x09) doesn't guarantee.

For a **short date format** hit capital **D** (note: lowercase **d** opens a diff view.) Configure it permanently by adding `show-date = short` to ~/.tigrc; or in a `[tig]` section in .git/configure or ~/.gitconfig.

To see an **entire change**:

- hit **Enter**. A sub pane will open in the lower half of the window.
- use **k**, **j** keys to scroll the change in the sub pane.
- at the same time, use the **up**, **down** keys to move from commit to commit.

Since tig is separate from git and apparently *nix specific, it probably requires cygwin to install on windows. But for **fedora** I believe the install commands are `$ su`, `(enter root password)`, `# yum install tig`. For **freebsd** try `% su`,  `(enter root password)`, `# pkg_add -r tig`.

---

By the way, tig is good for a lot more than a quick view of the log:
[Screenshots](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/screenshots/) &
[Manual](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/manual.html#views)

Comment: please provide full example. Writing `tig`in my console simply gives me an error `-bash: tig: command not found`

Comment: wow. this tool is fantastic, and surprisingly fast! brew install tig

Comment: if you use mac, brew install tig

Comment: on Windows, babun users can `pact install tig`

Answer (score 38):

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad %s (%an)' --date=short
```

or

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad %s | %an' --date=short
```

...riffing on cdunn2001's answer above:  I'd lose the author's e=mail and include just the author's name, as per Jesper and knittl, but in keeping with cdunn2001's idea of maintaining output in columns of constant width for ease of reading (great idea!). In lieu of a separate left justified column for author name, however, I wrap that flag at the end of the command with a parentheses or offset it with a pipe.  (Could really be any character that serves as a visual aid in reading the output...albeit might make sense to avoid back or forward slashes in order to reduce confusing the output with a directory or something.)

Sample output:

```
6fdd155 2015-08-10 Fixes casting error in doSave | John Doe
c4f4032 2015-08-10 Fix for IE save. Add help button. | Jane
29a24a6 2015-08-10 Fixes bug in Course | Mac
```

Answer (score 33):

Use predefined git alias, i.e.:

```
$ git work
```

Created once by command:

```
$ git config --global alias.work 'log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"'
```

https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Or more colored with graph:

```
$ git config --global alias.work 'log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %ar %C(auto)%d %Creset %s , %Cblue%cn" --graph --all'
```

[image]

Comment: one can have columns that line up and a graph https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229359/how-to-do-alignment-in-git-logs-with-graph

Answer (score 8):

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad  %s%x09%ae' --date=short
```

Result:

```
e17bae5 2011-09-30  Integrate from development -> main      nixon@whitehouse.gov
eaead2c 2011-09-30  More stuff that is not worth mentioning bgates@apple.com
eb6a336 2011-09-22  Merge branch 'freebase' into development        jobs@nirvana.org
```

Constant-width stuff is first. The least important part -- the email domain -- is last and easy to filter.

Answer (score 4):

To show the commits I have staged that are ready to push I do

```
git log remotes/trunk~4..HEAD --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%C(white) %ad %aN%x09%d%x09%s" --date=short | awk -F'\t' '{gsub(/[, ]/,"",$2);gsub(/HEAD/, "\033[1;36mH\033[00m",$2);gsub(/master/, "\033[1;32mm\033[00m",$2);gsub(/trunk/, "\033[1;31mt\033[00m",$2);print $1 "\t" gensub(/([\(\)])/, "\033[0;33m\\1\033[00m","g",$2) $3}' | less -eiFRXS
```

The output looks something like:

```
ef87da7 2013-01-17 haslers      (Hm)Fix NPE in Frobble
8f6d80f 2013-01-17 haslers      Refactor Frobble
815813b 2013-01-17 haslers      (t)Add Wibble to Frobble
3616373 2013-01-17 haslers      Add Foo to Frobble
3b5ccf0 2013-01-17 haslers      Add Bar to Frobble
a1db9ef 2013-01-17 haslers      Add Frobble Widget
```

Where the first column appears in yellow, and the 'H' 'm' and 't' in parentesis show the HEAD, master and trunk and appear in their usual "--decorate" colors

Here it is with line breaks so you can see what it's doing:

```
git log remotes/trunk~4..HEAD --date=short
    --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%C(white) %ad %aN%x09%d%x09%s"
    | awk -F'\t' '{
         gsub(/[, ]/,"",$2);
         gsub(/HEAD/, "\033[1;36mH\033[00m",$2);
         gsub(/master/, "\033[1;32mm\033[00m",$2);
         gsub(/trunk/, "\033[1;31mt\033[00m",$2);
         print $1 "\t" gensub(/([\(\)])/, "\033[0;33m\\1\033[00m","g",$2) $3}'
```

I have aliased to "staged" with:

```
git config alias.staged '!git log remotes/trunk~4..HEAD --date=short --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%C(white) %ad %aN%x09%d%x09%s" | awk -F"\t" "{gsub(/[, ]/,\"\",\$2);gsub(/HEAD/, \"\033[1;36mH\033[00m\",\$2);gsub(/master/, \"\033[1;32mm\033[00m\",\$2);gsub(/trunk/, \"\033[1;31mt\033[00m\",\$2);print \$1 \"\t\" gensub(/([\(\)])/, \"\033[0;33m\\\\\1\033[00m\",\"g\",\$2) \$3}"'
```

(Is there an easier way to escape that? it was a bit tricky to work out what needed escaping)

Comment: My current version of this script is ~300LOC and does a lot more:¶
- option to toggle oneline/multiline commit message¶
- show line whitespace/line ends in oneline mode. e.g:¶
- specify range via param¶
- Highlight issue #'s¶
- highlight /^- (Fix|Add|Refactor)/ in commit messages¶

Comment: For automated robust alias quoting, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39616600/5353461). 

Care to share your ~300LOC in a gist?

Comment: Thanks Tom! if I get round to posting that script (I'd need to remove some confidential/company specific stuff) I'll ping you here.

Answer (score 4):

```
git --no-pager log --pretty=tformat:"%C(yellow)%h %C(cyan)%ad %Cblue%an%C(auto)%d %Creset%s" --graph --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" -25
```

I use alias

```
alias gitlog='git --no-pager log --pretty=tformat:"%C(yellow)%h %C(cyan)%ad %Cblue%an%C(auto)%d %Creset%s" --graph --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" -25'
```

Differences: I use tformat and isodate without seconds and time zones , with --no-pager you will see  colors

Answer (score 2):

All aforementioned suggestions use `%s` placeholder for subject. I'll recommend to use `%B` because `%s` formatting [preserves new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35603023/2789312) and multiple lines commit message appears squashed.

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ai%x09%B"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try git log --pretty=fuller, it will show you:-
Author:
Author Date:
Commit:
Commit Date:

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in project folder:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %ar %C(auto)%d %Creset %s , %Cblue%cn" --graph --all
```

And if you like, add this line to your ~/.gitconfig:

```
[alias]
    ...
    list = log --pretty=format:\"%C(yellow)%h %ar %C(auto)%d %Creset %s, %Cblue%cn\" --graph --all
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna **specify a file or folder**, just add the path at the end:

- `%ad` = author date (format respects --date=option)
- `--date=raw` shows the date as seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), followed by a space, and then the timezone as an offset from UTC [Reference](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

```sh
git log -1 --pretty=format:"%ad" --date=raw path/to/your/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like this is what you are after:

```
git log --pretty=" %C(reset)%ad %C(Cyan)%an: %C(reset)%s"
```

(in personal note you should always has commit hash..)