# Git how to save a preset git log --format

Tags: git, formatting, logging

I really like the short git log format where I can see author, date and change description like this:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"
```

Which outputs:

```
  fbc3503 mads    Thu Dec 4 07:43:27 2008 +0000   show mobile if phone is null...   
  ec36490 jesper  Wed Nov 26 05:41:37 2008 +0000  Cleanup after [942]: Using timezon
  ae62afd tobias  Tue Nov 25 21:42:55 2008 +0000  Fixed #67 by adding time zone supp
  164be7e mads    Tue Nov 25 19:56:43 2008 +0000  fixed tests, and a 'unending appoi
```

(from stackoverflow question "[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441010/the-shortest-possible-output-from-git-log-containing-author-and-date/1441062#1441062)")

Now, the question is, how do I save this as a new format on my machine so I only have to write something like, for instance:

```
git log --format=jespers_favourite
```

Comment: I have fixed the answer, after your comment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Considering the git log manual page mentions:

```
--pretty[=<format>]
--format[=<format>]
```

> Pretty-print the contents of the commit logs in a given format, where  can be one of oneline, short, medium, full, fuller, email, raw and format:. When omitted, the format defaults to medium.

the `<format>` can only have predefined values.
That only leaves you the possibility to [define an **alias**](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) as a shortcut for that command.

```
[alias]
        jespers_favourite = log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"
```

or

```
[alias]
        compactlog = log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"
```

---

[Rokit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/996314/rokit) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441156/git-how-to-save-a-preset-git-log-format/1441176#comment131313251_1441176):

> Escaping the quotes worked until I tried adding custom colors.
> For that, I also had to add an additional set of regular quotes around the escaped ones, e.g.
>
> ```
> log --pretty=format:"\"%C(#9be3bc) %s\""
> ```

Comment: @ftassi Good point. I have restored the link (with the one you mention).

Comment: I needed to escape the quotes too, in order to make this work

Comment: @ftassi you needed to escape the quote in a `git config alias.xxx...` commands? Not in the `.config` file itself?

Comment: @VonC I've escaped them it the ~/.gitconfig file, here's a snippet of what I'm using https://gist.github.com/283ad42cd367ec35cf76

Comment: Escaping the quotes worked until I tried adding custom colors. For that, I also had to add an additional set of regular quotes around the escaped ones, e.g. `log --pretty=format:"\"%C(#9be3bc) %s\""`

Comment: @Rokit Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 47):

In newer versions of Git (confirmed with v1.7.8) it is possible to set **named pretty-print log formats** using `git config pretty.named_format`. These can be set at a *machine-wide, user or file level* with the `<file-option>` argument.

To create a log format called `jespers_favourite` or the whole machine use `--system`

```
git config --system pretty.jespers_favourite "%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"
```

For single user use '--global'

```
git config --global pretty.jespers_favourite "%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"
```

Leaving the `<file-option>` argument blank will default to setting the config file of the current repository, `.git/config` unless defined otherwise.

Comment: This is almost right, but there are a couple of important caveats: the name can't contain an underscore (at least in Git 1.7.10), and the custom format must begin with "format:" (or refer to one of the built-in formats).

Answer (score 10):

With recent versions of git (1.7… 2.21 here) you can change your default format to a named format or the format string. And while you're doing it you may as well add some [PRETTY FORMATS](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) auto colors. Also I find it easier to edit the file rather than use the commands; but I start with them to get the right config file format first, and then tinker.

## The default is changed with:

```sh
git config --global --add format.pretty \
"%C(yellow)%h%Creset%x09%Cred%<(13)%an%Creset%x09%Cblue%ad%Creset%x09%s"
```

Resulting in the addition to your `.gitconfig` of:

```
[format]
    pretty = %C(yellow)%h%Creset%x09%Cred%<(13)%an%Creset%x09%Cblue%ad%Creset%x09%s
```

It is, however, probably more useful to you to add a named format as mentioned in the later part of your question.

## A named format is added with:

```sh
git config --global pretty.dateline \
"format:%C(yellow)%h%Creset%x09%Cred%<(13)%an%Creset%x09%Cblue%ad%Creset%x09%s"
```

Or by adding to your `.gitconfig` as:

```
[pretty]
    dateline = format:%C(yellow)%h%Creset%x09%Cred%<(13)%an%Creset%x09%Cblue%ad%Creset%x09%s
```

## Used in combination:

If you add both, you could make them read:

```
[pretty]
    dateline = format:%C(yellow)%h%Creset%x09%Cred%<(13)%an%Creset%x09%Cblue%ad%Creset%x09%s

[format]
    pretty = dateline
```

### Caveats:

The difference in the `format:` prefix should be noted, and personally I like to leave the default pretty format as `medium`. As you know the `%ad` part can be modified by `--date=relative` or any of `default`, `iso8601`, `local`, `raw`, `relative`, `rfc2822`, `short` ; so I like to use it like:

```sh
git log -25 --pretty=dateline --date=short -- when/was/this/changed.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

You can configure the default pretty format using git-config. From the git-config documentation:

```
 format.pretty
           The default pretty format for log/show/whatchanged command, See git-log(1), git-show(1), git-whatchanged(1).
```

For example:

`git config --add format.pretty fuller`

or original poster's desired format:

`git config --add format.pretty "%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"`

Like with other git config settings, format.pretty may be set at the global, system, or repository scope (default).

Comment: FYI this changing the default format doesn't sound like what the question originally wanted, but it's a useful point to add.