# Git log output to XML, JSON, or YAML?

Tags: git, file, logging, version-control, io

This is a pretty simple question: as a Git newbie I was wondering if there's a way for me to output my git log to a file, preferably in some kind of serialized format like XML, JSON, or YAML. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

to output to a file:

```
git log > filename.log
```

To specify a format, like you want everything on one line

```
git log --pretty=oneline >filename.log
```

or you want it a format to be emailed via a program like sendmail

```
git log --pretty=email |email-sending-script.sh
```

to generate JSON, YAML or XML it looks like you need to do something like:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"
```

This gist (not mine) perfectly formats output in JSON:
https://gist.github.com/1306223

See also:

- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History
- [Git how to save a preset git log --format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441156/git-how-to-save-a-preset-git-log-format)
- [How to parse the output of git log](http://blog.lost-theory.org/post/how-to-parse-git-log-output/)

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks! For future readers, here's a link to the shortcodes used by "format": http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html

Comment: Hmm. Well, all the references I can find point to that same broken page, so shame on whoever took down the git documentation without a redirect. Boo.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but the `%s` for the commit message only shows the first line

Comment: More direct link to format codes: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_pretty_formats

Comment: @Heiko Rupp: To print the full commit message use `%b` or `%B` and you could also use `%N` to get any commit notes. You'll also have to figure out how to escape the line breaks. Fwiw for my purposes the first line of the commit message is always sufficient. If you really want to do full text search on commit messages (and patches, for that matter) maybe you should look at indexing your Git log with Solr as described here: http://www.garysieling.com/blog/discovering-senior-developers-from-source-code-history

Comment: Hey, I'm the author of the referenced gist, dropping by to say that I've added another shell script which supports JSON output for "files changed" data from `git log --numstat`. Plus a couple other notes: first, **if you are worried about escaping special characters in commit messages** then use `%f` instead of `%s` in the format string. Secondly, the "format codes" are shown whenever you type `git help log`. They are listed under the heading "placeholders" (if you don't know how to search the Git help page it's easy: just press the `/` key, type "placeholders" then hit the RETURN key).

Answer (score 16):

I did something like this to create a minimal web api / javascript widget that would show the last 5 commits in any repository.

If you are doing this from any sort of scripting language, you *really* want to generate your JSON with something other than `"` for your quote character, so that you can escape real quotes in commit messages. (You *will* have them sooner or later, and it's not nice for that to break things.)

So I ended up with the terrifying but unlikely delimiter `^@^` and this command-line.

```js
var cmd = 'git log -n5 --branches=* --pretty=format:\'{%n^@^hash^@^:^@^%h^@^,%n^@^author^@^:^@^%an^@^,%n^@^date^@^:^@^%ad^@^,%n^@^email^@^:^@^%aE^@^,%n^@^message^@^:^@^%s^@^,%n^@^commitDate^@^:^@^%ai^@^,%n^@^age^@^:^@^%cr^@^},\'';
```

Then (in node.js) my http response body is constructed from `stdout` of the call to `git log` thusly:

```js
var out = ("" + stdout).replace(/"/gm, '\\"').replace(/\^@\^/gm, '"');
if (out[out.length - 1] == ',') {
    out = out.substring (0, out.length - 1);
}
```

and the result is nice JSON that doesn't break with quotes.

Comment: A quick workaround for escaping special characters in commit messages would be to use `%f` instead of `%s` in the format string: `%f: sanitized subject line, suitable for a filename`

Comment: FWIW, a project using this approach [is here](https://github.com/timboudreau/gittattle)

Comment: Worth mentioning you can now do this using ES6 template strings, negating the need to use the ^@^ delimiter and node string replacement.

Comment: @Gary Could you provide a short example of how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this in Powershell to get git logdata and save it as json or other format:

```
$header = @("commit","tree","parent","refs","subject","body","author","commiter") 
[string] $prettyGitLogDump= (git log MyCoolSite.Web-1.4.0.002..HEAD --pretty=format:'%H|%T|%P|%D|%s|%b|%an|%cn;') 
$gldata = foreach ($commit in $prettyGitLogDump.Replace("; ",';') -split  ";", 0, "multiline") {
          $prop = $commit -split "\|"
          $hash = [ordered]@{}
          for ($i=0;$i -lt $header.count;$i++) {$hash.add($header[$i],$prop[$i])} 
          [pscustomobject]$hash
}
$gldata |  ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path "GitLog.json"
```

The headernames:

> "commit","tree","parent","refs","subject","body","author","commiter"

have to be in sync with datafields :

> --pretty=format:'%H|%T|%P|%D|%s|%b|%an|%cn;'

See [prettyformat docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats).
I choose pipe **|** as a separator. I am taking a risc that it is not used in the commit message. I used semicolon **;** as a sep for every commit. I should of course chosen something else. You could try to code some clever regular expression to match and check if your separators are used in the commit message. Or you could code more complex regularexpression to match split point or [code a powershell scriptblock to define the split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6#scriptblock).

The hardest line in the code to figure out was.

> prettyGitLogDump.Replace("; ",';') -split  ";", 0, "multiline"

[You have to set option multiline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6#options) becuase there can be CR/LF in the messages and then split stops - you can only set multiline if nr of split is given. Therefore second paramvalue 0 which means all.

*(The Replace("; ",';') is just a hack I get a space after the first commit. So I remove space after commit separator. Probably there is a better solution.)*

Anyway i think this could be a workable solution for windows users or powershells fans that want the log from git to see who made the commit and why.

Answer (score 4):

git log has no provisions to escape quotes, backslashes, newlines etc., which makes *robust* direct JSON output impossible (unless you limit yourself to  subset of fields with predictable content e.g. hash & dates).

However, the `%w([width[,indent1[,indent2]]])` specifier can indent lines, making it possible to emit robust YAML with arbitrary fields!  The params are same as [`git shortlog -w`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#Documentation/git-shortlog.txt--wltwidthgtltindent1gtltindent2gt):

> Linewrap the output by wrapping each line at width. The first line of each entry is indented by *indent1* spaces, and the second and subsequent lines are indented by *indent2* spaces.
> *width*, *indent1*, and *indent2* default to 76, 6 and 9 respectively.
> If *width* is 0 (zero) then indent the lines of the output without wrapping them.

The YAML syntax that guarantees predictable parsing of indented text (with no other quoting needed!) is [YAML block literal](https://yaml-multiline.info/), not folded, with explicit number of spaces to strip e.g. `|-2`.

- The `-` option strips trailing newlines, which technically is lossy — it loses distinction between 1 vs. 4 trailing newlines, which are possible to produce with `git commit --cleanup=verbatim` — so in theory you might want `|+2` for multiline fields.  Personally, I prefer treating one-line commit messages as strings without newline characters.

Example:

```bash
git log --pretty=format:'- hash: %H
  author_date: %aI
  committer_date: %cI
  author: |-2
    %w(0,0,4)%an <%ae>%w(0,0,0)
  committer: |-2
    %w(0,0,4)%cn <%ae>%w(0,0,0)
  message: |-2
    %w(0,0,4)%B%w(0,0,0)'
```

`%w` affects later % placeholders but also literal lines so resetting the indent with `%w(0,0,0)` is necessary, otherwise text like   `committer:` will also get indented.

output fragment (on [reconstructed unix history](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo)):

```
- hash: 0d54a08ec260f3d554db334092068680cdaff26a
  author_date: 1972-11-21T14:35:16-05:00
  committer_date: 1972-11-21T14:35:16-05:00
  author: |-2
    Ken Thompson <ken@research.uucp>
  committer: |-2
    Ken Thompson <ken@research.uucp>
  message: |-2
    Research V2 development
    Work on file cmd/df.s
    
    Co-Authored-By: Dennis Ritchie <dmr@research.uucp>
    Synthesized-from: v2

- hash: 4bc99f57d668fda3158d955c972b09c89c3725bd
  author_date: 1972-07-22T17:42:11-05:00
  committer_date: 1972-07-22T17:42:11-05:00
  author: |-2
    Dennis Ritchie <dmr@research.uucp>
  committer: |-2
    Dennis Ritchie <dmr@research.uucp>
  message: |-2
    Research V2 development
    Work on file c/nc0/c00.c
    
    Synthesized-from: v2
```

Note I didn't put quotes around the dates, to show off parsing as native YAML timestamp type.  Support may vary (especially since YAML v1.2 spec delegated things like timestamps and booleans to app-dependent *schema*?), so it may be pragmatic to make them "strings"...

To convert YAML to JSON, you can pipe through [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/convert) or [similar tools](https://github.com/fiatjaf/awesome-jq#command-line).
Or a short in-place script e.g.

```rb
| ruby -e '
require "yaml"
require "json"
# to parse timestamps
require "date"
data = YAML.safe_load(STDIN.read(), permitted_classes: [Date, Time])
puts(JSON.pretty_generate(data))
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Behold https://github.com/dreamyguy/gitlogg, the last `git-log => JSON` parser you will ever need!

Some of **Gitlogg**'s features are:

- Parse the `git log` of **multiple repositories into one `JSON` file**.
- Introduced **`repository`** key/value.
- Introduced **`files changed`**, **`insertions`** and **`deletions`** keys/values.
- Introduced **`impact`** key/value, which represents the cumulative changes for the commit (`insertions` - `deletions`).
- Sanitise double quotes `"` by converting them to single quotes `'` on all values that allow or are created by user input, like `subject`.
- Nearly all the `pretty=format:` placeholders are available.
- Easily include / exclude which keys/values will be parsed to `JSON` by commenting out/uncommenting the available ones.
- Easy to read code that's thoroughly commented.
- Script execution feedback on console.
- Error handling (since path to repositories needs to be set correctly).

[image: Success, the JSON was parsed and saved.]
Success, the JSON was parsed and saved.

[image: Error 001]
Error 001: path to repositories does not exist.

[image: Error 002]
Error 002: path to repositories exists, but is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, for json, you need to escape quotes. This script works quite good:

```
git log --pretty=format:'{%n  \"commit\": \"%H\",%n  \"author\": \"%an\",%n  \"date\": \"%ad\",%n  \"message\": \"%f\"%n},'
```

The result is like this:

```
{
  "commit": "e31231231239a67e42175e9201823e70",
  "author": "jack",
  "date": "Thu Oct 19 11:20:39 2023 +0200",
  "message": "commit message 1"
},
{
  "commit": "14594ad80d4949b0f1c10b180740083qe",
  "author": "jill",
  "date": "Wed Oct 18 11:07:02 2023 +0200",
  "message": "commit message 2"
},
{
  "commit": "123asd1231g2f3gh12f3h12f3",
  "author": "john",
  "date": "Wed Oct 18 10:56:51 2023 +0200",
  "message": "commit message 3"
},
```

You need to add `[` and `]` to start and end

Answer (score 0):

There is also `jc` which can convert the output of many Unix tools into JSON. To get a git log in JSON and then filter it with `jq`, you would simply do:

```bash
jc git log | jq '.[] | ...'
```

https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc