# Can I escape chars in git log output?

Tags: git

I want to post process the output of `git log` and have been playing with the `--pretty` settings. When I e.g. do

```
--pretty=format:'{"sha":"%h","message":"%B","author":"%aN <%aE>","commit":"%cE","date":"%cD"}
```

I get some JSON-like output; when I put in a `{` or `}` or even a `"` into the commit message this messes up my output.

Is there a way to tell `git log` to escape those chars e.g. by prepending a `\`?

There are two similar questions [Git log output to XML, JSON or YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600445/git-log-output-to-xml-json-or-yaml) and [Git log output preferably as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327276/parsing-git-log-output-preferably-as-xml), but they both do not address the escaping of the special chars (e.g. if in the XML case I put `<foo>` in my commit message, the resulting XML will be broken).

Comment: You should use `git rev-list` for scripting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escaping strings isn't Git's job; `git log` doesn't have anything that'll help you do that. To achieve what you're after, you'll need something like `sed` to do the string editing for you.

Try this (should work in most shells, but I've only checked in Cygwin bash):

```
function escape_chars {
    sed -r 's/(\{\}")/\\\1/g'
}
function format {
    sha=$(git log -n1 --pretty=format:%h $1 | escape_chars)
    message=$(git log -n1 --pretty=format:%B $1 | escape_chars)
    author=$(git log -n1 --pretty=format:'%aN <%aE>' $1 | escape_chars)
    commit=$(git log -n1 --pretty=format:%cE $1 | escape_chars)
    date=$(git log -n1 --pretty=format:%cD $1 | escape_chars)
    echo "{\"sha\":\"$sha\",\"message\":\"$message\",\"author\":\"$author\",\"commit\":\"$commit\",\"date\":\"$date\"}"
}

for hash in $(git rev-list)
do
  format $hash
done
```

The above will escape `{` and `}` and not `\`, although from [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) both `\{` and `\}` are invalid escapes; only `\` and `"` need to be escaped. (Replace the `sed` expression with `sed -r 's/("\\)/\\\1/g'` for true JSON output.)

I've also left the "commit" value as it is in your example, although the `%cE` command actually gives the commiter's email address; I'm not sure if that's what you intended.

(This now includes a [correct but rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1872404) by [macrobug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226508/macrobug). Thanks!)

Comment: More recent versions of git require `git rev-list --all`

Comment: rev-list doesn't escape either

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this could be done using `git log` only but a simple other solution would be to use `git log` to generate a CSV-like output (with tab-separated field) and pipe this output into a python script which handles the JSON generation with correct quote.

Comment: Wouldn't a , in CSV also need to be escaped? Or will `git log` do that?