# How can I set special chars in the git log --pretty=format?

Tags: git

I am learning Git. I wrote the command:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"author: %an, %ae\ncommiter: %cn, %ce\nInfo: %s"
```

I expected `\n` will be interpreted like a new line char:

```
author: CharliePoole, charliepoole@gmail.com
commiter: CharliePoole, charliepoole@gmail.com
Info: Merge pull request #563 from nunit/issue-562
```

But I get this output:

> author: CharliePoole, charliepoole@gmail.com\ncommiter:
>   CharliePoole,
> charliepoole@gmail.com\nInfo: Merge pull request #563
>   from nunit/issue-562

Also I read this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301673/can-i-escape-chars-in-git-log-output):

> Escaping **strings** isn't Git's job; `git log` doesn't have anything
>   that'll help you do that.

So, is it impossible for escape chars too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two different kind of things. From `man git`:

> The format: format allows you to specify which information you want to show. It works a little bit like printf format, with the notable exception that you get a newline with %n instead of \n.

Answer: use `%n`