# Making git show to show information in a machine parseable format

Tags: git, git-show

I have read [parsing git log output, preferably as xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327276/parsing-git-log-output-preferably-as-xml) but that does not help. I am trying to get the following information about a Git tag.

1. User that created the tag
2. Message associated with tag creation if any
3. The name of the tag (I know this as I already pass this) but I want them in the output so that I can just pass the whole output back to my caller
4. The latest commit id on that tag

I would prefer them as CSV or space/tab separated values so I was trying to use the --format option. I was trying things like

```
 git show my_label_name --pretty=format:"%an, %cn" --quiet
```

but this does not produce what I want. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

```
git cat-file tag <tag_name>
```

will give you the actual contents of the file that represents that tag (helpfully unpacked and uncompressed).

#### Example

```
$ git init
$ touch README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m 'Initial commit'
$ git tag -a foo -m 'Tagging foo'
$ git cat-file tag foo
object 91654534f5ac138a3adb56a9e6dc3bacae5bae53
type commit
tag foo
tagger Peter Lundgren <peter@peterlundgren.com> 1369779403 -0400

Tagging foo
```

Comment: Is this Machine parseable? i.e, I have to parse every line. I was thinking if git itself should support some json, csv, tab or newline separated output

Comment: Well Git parses it; this is literally how git stores this data.