# Get the commit hash for a tag

Tags: git

It is related to [Making git show to show information in a machine parseable format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795512/making-git-show-to-show-information-in-a-machine-parseable-format) but I am getting tired of the fact that I now have to do a lot of parsing to get the commit hash.

Can someone give me a command that will print the commit hash (and only the commit hash) tag for a given git tag? I was hoping

```
git show mylabel --pretty=format:"%H" --quiet
```

Would just print me my commit # but it says

```
tag mylabel
Tagger: user <user@x.com>

Some comment

446a52cb4aff90d0626b8232aba8c40235c16245
```

I was expecting one line of output with just the commit line but I now have to parse for the last line?

Comment: I think @michas' solution should be the accepted answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell which commit a tag points to in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862423/how-to-tell-which-commit-a-tag-points-to-in-git)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What about `git log -1 --format=format:"%H" mylabel`

EDIT:

Actually a better solution would be :

```
git show-ref -s mylabel
```

**WARNING This only works for Unannotated tags** For a more general and safer command see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1862542/1586965

EDIT bis: As mentioned in the comments, be careful with annotated commits (which are objects of their own). To have a more generic solution, read @michas answer.

You can see the difference when you do a `git show-ref -d mylabel`.

---

**Resources:**

- [git show-ref](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-ref.html)

Comment: Be aware that this does NOT work for annotated tags, for which the tag is different from its commit.

Comment: The `git log -1` is an useful option since I can play around with the format. However the git log command gives me the commit hash and commit name not the TAG's hash and the tagger. Is there any way I can find that using git-log?

Comment: This is going to show multiple things if there are also remote branches labeled `mylabel`

Comment: (which would interfere with scripting)

Answer (score 21):

`git help rev-parse` says:

```
   <rev>^{}, e.g. v0.99.8^{}
       A suffix ^ followed by an empty brace pair means the object could be a tag, and dereference the tag recursively until a non-tag object is found.
```

Generally you use `tag^{}` to refer to that commit.

You have two different kind of tags:

- lightweight tags are just pointers to an existing commit
- annotated tags are objects on there own which contain a pointer to a separate commit object

Use `git rev-parse tag` to get the SHA1 of the tag itself.

Use `git rev-parse tag^{}` to get the SHA1 of the underlaying commit.

For lightweight tags both are the same. For annotated tags they are not.

You can also use `git show-ref -d tag`, which will show you both the SHA1 of the tag and the SHA1 of the associated commit.

There is also `git show tag` to give you details about an (annotated) tag.

Answer (score 5):

`git rev-parse mylabel^{}` should do what you want. See [`man gitrevisions`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html) for more info on `^{}` and other operators.

Answer (score 5):

```
git log <tag or branch> -1 --pretty=%H
```

`-1`: tells it to only print 1 commit

`--pretty=%H`: tells it to only print the full hash

Answer (score -1):

just a guess: try "git show --pretty=format:"%H" --quiet mylabel"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862423/git-how-to-tell-which-commit-a-tag-points-to