# how to obtain a JSON representation of a Git/GitHub reposity

Tags: linux, git, github

I'm working on a prototype of a game that will use the information of a Git repository, its branch, merges, etc, as a source for the game's levels.

Is there a way to get a Git repository 'history' and save it in JSON format? Even better, is it possible to get a JSON representation of a GitHub repo?

I would love to let the Linux repo be the last stage from the game and also for people to use their own local repos.

- for the sake of completeness, part of my question (using only a Git client) was answered here: [Git log output to XML, JSON, or YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600445/git-log-output-to-xml-json-or-yaml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Github API to get all this information

http://developer.github.com/

Repo Collaborators: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/

Repo Commits : http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/

Repo Content : http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/

Repo Forks : http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/

Sample URL to get the commits of github.com/holman/play

```
https://api.github.com/repos/holman/play/commits
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [developer API documentation](http://developer.github.com/v3/)?

The exact information that you need will depend on what, exactly, you mean by "JSON representation of a GitHub repo," as it relates to how GitHub exposes it, but the details can be found in their [Repositories section.](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/)

Overall, the GitHub API is a RESTful interface, so it follows the typical REST rules. Given that they're a Ruby shop, it will likely also follow Ruby's practices for REST APIs, which may help you in experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have pointed out ways to approach this with the github API.  Your question also leaves open the possibility of doing this with just *git*, not github.  The great thing about JSON is that it's just text, so you can generate it with just `git log`.

```
$ echo "[" && git log -n5 --pretty=format:\"%H\", && echo "]"
[
"216e8824cfac3d3a46eac23fb177566829f2f236",
"8b0357b71fa824114f9db96954b364a8f815fd50",
"bd394fd40184df8b22e45fb6aaa1fc1c3c6dc31a",
"c35af70eaedcdd05b56496e555f33c65286e85ba",
"9e65dfd39de1732bc114bee184f595a6f091680c",
]
```

I know you will eventually need more detail than that, but it's a starting point.

OK, here's another example.  This is fun.

```
$ echo "[" && git log -n5 --pretty=format:'{ "author": "%an", "subject":"%s" }', && echo "]"
[
{ "author": "Saul Torrell", "subject":"June 21 release - operator systems" },
{ "author": "Saul Torrell", "subject":"Missing topic for june 11 release." },
{ "author": "Saul Torrell", "subject":"June 11 release." },
{ "author": "Saul Torrell", "subject":"new topic." },
{ "author": "Saul Torrell", "subject":"Added extra sauce to the frobnicator." },
]
```