# Git log JSON *with changed files*

Tags: json, git, perl

I need to get the output of a git log command formatted as JSON. I like the approach suggested in [Git log output to XML, JSON, or YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600445/git-log-output-to-xml-json-or-yaml) to use a custom git log pretty formatter and a light layer of perl processing on top using the command [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/textarcana/1306223/raw/bf185bdf6dc2a70316d36769a7d31584afc2fd95/git-log2json.sh):

```
git log \
--pretty=format:'{%n  "commit": "%H",%n  "author": "%an <%ae>",%n  "date": "%ad",%n  "message": "%f"%n},' \
$@ | \
perl -pe 'BEGIN{print "["}; END{print "]\n"}' | \
perl -pe 's/},]/}]/'
```

This works fantastic for getting those certain fields, but I also need the list of files changed that is returned from using the --name-status flag included in the JSON output.

I've tried various approaches but I'm at a loss at how to approach this. My gut tells me I'm missing something obvious. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added `--name-only` parameter support to the original Noah Sussman's script so you can get the list of changed files using this command:

```
git log2json --name-only
```

The amended script is [here](https://gist.github.com/dmegorov/b64dcea2eed31e02c916fc6ed9111f4f#file-git-log2json-sh).

Answer (score 0):

I know little about Perl. Here is my way to get the changed files of a commit. Hope it helps.

```
git log -1 <sha1> --pretty=%h --name-only | tail -n +3
```