# Get only the content of each commit in a json ? ( git diff json)

Tags: json, git, github, git-commit

So I'm storring on my github all the differences I get on a json file during time ( I call an api that updates each time the json and only store the differences). To give you an idea ; It's the changes of availability, either an id is available or not. 
What I'm trying to do now : I want to get the content of each commit in a json file in my local machine. SO later I can loop through all the json files in sequence using nodejs or python and then generate a CSV with the data that interest me.

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a couple of Gists adding support of `log2json` command to `git`:

- https://gist.github.com/textarcana/1306223#file-git-log2json-sh - the original `log2json` command implementation
- https://gist.github.com/dmegorov/b64dcea2eed31e02c916fc6ed9111f4f#file-git-log2json-sh - my version of the above with support of `--name-only` parameter

References:

- [Git log output to XML, JSON, or YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600445/git-log-output-to-xml-json-or-yaml)
- [Git log JSON *with changed files*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106607/git-log-json-with-changed-files)