# How can I get the whole git graph as an object?

Tags: git

I want to process the graph that represents my git repo, similar to output of  `git log --graph`.

Are there tools that can generate an output as a kind of an object, e.g. as JSON or something that can be processed by a program easier than parsing the raw output of `git log`?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4600561/2295034

Comment: Use `git rev-list --parents <start-points>`. The output is *n* lines long: one for each commit node reachable from the given start points, followed by its parent node IDs separated by white-space. In other words each line is the identity of the vertex in the graph, followed by the identities of each outgoing arc for that vertex. (Use `--all` to get every `refs/*` reference as a starting point. This omits reflog entries but otherwise gets you everything—possibly excluding `HEAD` itself in some Git versions).