# Transform git output into a JSON File

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, git, github

I using:

```
 git log --all --pretty=format:'%n{%n%d%n  "commit hash": "%H",%n  "author":     
    "%an",%n  "author_email": "%ae",%n  "date": "%ad",%n  "message": "%f"%n}'
```

to get the log of all the commits with the differents branches of a github repository, what I need is to transform the output into a .json file to can use as variable in a javascript code.

Comment: Where is this git log command executed ? in a server side's javascript?

Comment: If I run in the bash of git I get a output similar to a json file so what I want is transform that output in a actual .json file

Comment: @user3808826 where you think I should run the git log command?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/textarcana/1306223 this link help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git log output to XML, JSON, or YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600445/git-log-output-to-xml-json-or-yaml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, it is more of a bash command question

```
git log --all --pretty=format:'%n{%n%d%n  "commit hash": "%H",%n  "author": "%an",%n  "author_email": "%ae",%n  "date": "%ad",%n  "message": "%f"%n}'| grep -v "origin" | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/}{/}, {/g' | sed -e 's/^/[/' |sed -e 's/$/]/' > gitlog.json
```

Comment: Note that if the author name or email address contain double quotes, this will malfunction. It's up to whoever uses this to decide how much to trust those fields.

Comment: How can I get the json file in order?