# git: timezone and timestamp format

Tags: git, timezone, format, timestamp, timezone-offset

From git I can get the timestamp:

```
"2011-10-04 12:58:36 -0600"
```

but is there any way to show it as:

```
"2011-10-04 06:58:36"
```

So all I want is to get rid of the -0600 timezone offset. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: FYI,  `2011-10-04 12:58:36 -0600` would be `2011-10-04 18:58:36` UTC.  You converted incorrectly in your example.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

If you ask about git log, you can try and select most correct form from:

```
git log --date={relative,local,default,iso,rfc}
```

`--date=local` seems to be the best candidate.

To make this permanent, use `git config --global log.date local`.

Comment: To make this "permanent", use "git config --global log.date local".

Comment: `local` works. Apparently, a commit includes its own timezone, but `local` translates them all to the local timezone. However, I really want ISO or RFC translated to a single timezone. Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Ah! `--date=iso-strict-local` for strict ISO8601. Sweet!

Comment: I don't know why `--date=local` with `iso` format is not working my Ubuntu machines. I am still getting TZ offset. Any help please

Comment: I added your comment on how to make this permanent, to the answer itself @rickumali. Thanks

Comment: Note that this only seems to be recogniced by the `%cd` placeholder when used with `--pretty=format:`, as documented at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats

Answer (score 40):

```
TZ=UTC git log --date=local
```

in order to get non-local-timezone one-timezone output.

Comment: `TZ=UTC git log --date=iso-local` to use ISO 8601

Comment: Or `--date='format-local:%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ'` for a compact ISO 8601 format (or any other format).

Comment: i use `date = format-local:%a %d-%b-%Y %H:%M` to give `Fri 05-Oct-2018 19:55`. Here is the list of date formats https://stackoverflow.com/a/34778736/58678

Answer (score 39):

```
git log --date=local
```

Does the trick.

```
git config --global log.date local
```

Comment: When I run: `git log --date=local --pretty=format:"%ai,%an,%ae,%s"`, I still get timezone offset.

Doesn't `--data=local` work with **iso** dates?

Comment: @user2436428 if you check [git log documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) search for _format:<string>_ you will see you need to use: _**%ad**: author date (format respects --date= option)_ instead of _**%ai**: author date, ISO 8601-like format_

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, using `git log --date=local` as explained in previous answers changes the output format.

To keep the format as asked (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm`) I had to use:

```
git log --date=iso-local
```

But that only works on git 2.7 or above.

Answer (score 10):

To get the format (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:hh`), you can use:

```
git log --date=format:%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M
```

Works beautifully with Git Standup too: https://github.com/kamranahmedse/git-standup

Answer (score 7):

A full command line answer:

```
TZ=GMT git show -s --format=%cd --date=iso-local
```

Answer (score 3):

jveerman's post was really helpful:

> If you want to display the git date in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format:

```
DATE=$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%ad" --date=iso)
echo "Date: ${DATE::20}"
```

For log format I was able to add this

```
[log]
date=format:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

to my ~/.gitconfig

but getting the same nicely formatted date/time added automatically to my commit messages was an ordeal. I found nothing helpful until I added this to the .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg file:

```
DATE=$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%ad" --date=iso)
echo "${DATE::20}" >> $1
```

If you're mainly using the Desktop app, it's lovely to have the exact time of change shown with the commit listing!

Is there any way to make this global, so I don't have to edit each local repo's prepare-commit-msg file ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the git date in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format:

DATE=$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%ad" --date=iso)
echo "Date: ${DATE::20}"