# Retrieving git log in YYYY-MM-DD format in local time zone

Tags: git

To get `YYYY-MM-DD` format for dates `git log --date=iso` is used.
To force dates in your local time zone`git log --date=local` is used.

I was trying to combine both the options but it was a failure. 
So is there a way (`git log` command) to get date (`YYYY-MM-DD` format) in my local time zone ?

Comment: It is a bit of an odd question because ISO format includes a timezone specifier...

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: timezone and timestamp format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651644/git-timezone-and-timestamp-format)

Comment: I found an archive of same question in GIT http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/orthogonal-cases-of-log-date-option-td2414018.html I'm not sure what was concluded...

Comment: With git 2.7 (Q4 2015), you will be able to use `git log --date=iso-local`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32990722/6309)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With git 2.7, use:

```
git log  --date=iso-local
```

git 2.7 (Q4 2015), which introduces `-local` as an instruction.

It means that, in addition of:

```
--date=(relative|local|default|iso|iso-strict|rfc|short|raw)
```

you will also have:

```
--date=(relative-local|default-local|iso-local|iso-strict-local|rfc-local|short-local|raw-local)
```

You now can ask for any date format **using the local timezone**.

---

See [commit 99264e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99264e93fc87bdd61f646c53878782947d476da8), [commit db7bae2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db7bae25ed8e80a7afad9a6a9240819528c5192c), [commit dc6d782](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc6d782c5d2526b251061daffc3e74d15c8c7095), [commit f3c1ba5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3c1ba502628cf0b6e8674f07c3850b21f365965), [commit f95cecf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f95cecf43335dd8e80e954c2f998dc0e8b0dd070), [commit 4b1c5e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b1c5e1d268fa1e7b4344e7d94de1edc5ead49a5), [commit 8f50d26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f50d263d70702c9409eb17cce10ea5b0831223a), [commit 78a8441](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78a844160bd1273bad89fdc0df13a1037ab4b1a4), [commit 2df4e29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2df4e29c85dee2fe8b89e7878a38b59062e103ef) (03 Sep 2015) by [John Keeping (`johnkeeping`)](https://github.com/johnkeeping).
See [commit add00ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/add00ba2de971e0c5ba00f1f02b73c5534079d2c), [commit 547ed71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/547ed71636dbfab2dc303ba8cabb29c2cab22f1e) (03 Sep 2015) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7b09c45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b09c459d346d9bf30ab07921a9b0ee91405d104), 05 Oct 2015)</sup>

See **[git log date format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32990187/6309)** for more.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. That looks promising but not satisfying. Where is the point stil adding the tz offset if all times are in your local timezone? This is just pollution. I have added [my comment](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b09c459d346d9bf30ab07921a9b0ee91405d104#commitcomment-13636084) ot the merge.

Comment: @Michael-O this is orthogonal to the date format. The format does not change. Its ability to use the local timezone does.

Comment: I understand but this is half-breed to me.

Answer (score 12):

This can also be configured using `git-config`:

```
git config [--global] log.date iso-local
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time passed since the question, but this link was one of the first in google, and it had no answer.

So for people who find it: what you want is `--date=format-local:'%F'` (or `%F %R` for time too).

Answer (score -1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34778736/907576) (since Git v2.6.0-rc0) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735971/907576) (hack for older versions)

Answer (score -2):

try this ..

```
git log --date='short' --date=local
```

Comment: The second --date option overrides the first one.