# git log: How do I change the time zone and format of date at the same time?

Tags: git, datetime, formatting, timezone, git-log

I use this command in Git Bash:

```
git log -1 --date=local --pretty=format:'%ad' ce40c0f8f02e83892eb185aabea306ee2a3ab10e
```

I want to display the date in local time zone AND as `DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS`.

It seems I can either change the time zone to local (`--date=local`) or change the format (`--date=format:'%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'`), but cannot seem to do both together.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [Retrieving git log in YYYY-MM-DD format in local time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17910312/11725753)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it:

```
git log -1 --date='format-local:%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' \
           --pretty=format:'%H; %s; %an; %ae; %ad; %cn; %ce; %cd' \
           ce40c0f8f02e83892eb185aabea306ee2a3ab10e
```