# How to get "git log" with "--pretty=format" to show "human" dates but with local timezone?

Tags: git

I want to use `git log` with `--pretty=format:` so I can build a custom format.  I'm having trouble with the "author date" part, which I want in "human" format.

I first tried:

```bash
$ git log -1 --pretty=format:"%ah" faa7126
Fri Jan 12 00:06
```

The problem is that the date is not displaying the date/time in my local time zone (the author is 10 hours ahead), nor does it even indicate what time zone it's in (with something like `+0200`).

I can get the local time zone with:

```bash
$ git log -1 --date=local --pretty=format:"%ad" faa7126
Thu Jan 11 14:06:51 2024
```

But the problem with that is that it's not "human" format. If I try this:

```bash
$ git log -1 --date=local --pretty=format:"%ah" faa7126
Fri Jan 12 00:06
```

I get "human" format but still don't get my local time zone (`--date=local` doesn't have any effect).

How do I get "human" format *and* my local time zone? Is there perhaps a bug in `git`?

I've read [Retrieving git log in YYYY-MM-DD format in local time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910312/retrieving-git-log-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-local-time-zone) but that question does not have my requirement of "human" format.

**EDIT:** I've since discovered that this behavior seems to depend on how long ago the commit was.  For a certain range of commit ages, the output will append a time zone indication (such as `+0200`) in the "human" format.

Comment: If you want a specific format in the local timezone it's `format-local:...`, as shown in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---dateltformatgt

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I don't want a "specific" format... I want "human" format.

Comment: I reopened the question, this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910312/retrieving-git-log-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-local-time-zone.

Comment: I think that _is_ behaving as documented - `%ad` -> _"author date (format respects --date= option)"_, `%ah` -> _"author date, human style"_ (implicitly _doesn't_ respect --date=). `%ad` with `--date=human-local`, maybe? Also your examples are a little confusing - if the commits are being made at +10 then isn't that midnight your time, or are folks pulling all-nighters?

Comment: @jonrsharpe You yourself quoted the documentation: "human format shows the timezone if the timezone does not match the current time-zone".  I am using "human format" (`%ah`) and it is **not** showing the timezone (e.g. `+0200`), even though the current timezone is different.

Comment: I just fixed the formatting in that answer, and was responding in the comment above to your question's content (repeated in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77840129/how-to-get-git-log-with-pretty-format-to-show-human-dates-but-with-local?noredirect=1#comment137227332_77840211)) that _"`--date=local` doesn't have any effect"_ with `%ah` - it's not supposed to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ok, but my point is why not.  It would be useful and there would be no downside. In any event, the "human" format still does not follow the documentation of showing the timezone, which seems like a bug.

Comment: _"why not"_ isn't really an SO-appropriate question - because the git CLI maintainers decided so. If you think there's a bug in `git` itself see https://git-scm.com/community.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it's not that they're "pulling all-nighters", it's that they're working the hours of the team, which involves working during their night (and not during their day)... aka "shift work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you want is supported by git. `human` showing localtime is not supported – the format is documented as:

> shows the timezone if the timezone does not match the current time-zone

In general, if you pass multiple `--date==` flags, only the latest has any effect.

---

Regarding the **display of timezone offsets in `human`**, the logic is as follows:

- The time is displayed iff the commit was made in the current year.
- The timezone is displayed iff the commit was made in the current month and was made less than 5 days ago.
- (The date is displayed exactly when the timezone is not displayed)

Is that a bug? Probably not, it is documented as follows in [the source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/186b115d3062e6230ee296d1ddaa0c4b72a464b5/date.c#L219):

> - Hide timezone if showing date.
> - Hide weekday and time if showing year.
>
> The logic here is two-fold:
>
> 1. only show details when recent enough to matter
> 2. keep the maximum length "similar", and in check

Comment: But it does *not* follow the documentation.  As you can see in my output, it does *not* show the time zone, even though it does *not* match the current timezone. Showing the timezone would involve something like "+0200".  That indicates a bug.  I will edit my question to underscore that.

Comment: It's also curious that `--date=local` has no effect on "human" format.  While that may not explicitly contradict the documentation, it certainly would be an improvement if it did have an effect, with no downside that I can think of.

Comment: That is intended behavior, I extended my answer.

Comment: Excellent and very complete and well researched answer! Are you a `git` contributor? My only remaining quibble would be to question how the **time** could be considered "useful" without the **offset** as well, and that without displaying the offset, it misleads the user into thinking that the time is in the *user's* timezone, since the display format is indistinguishable from one that is.

Comment: Thanks for these kind words. I am not a git contributor, I just had a look at the source on github. I agree with you that the output format is rather confusing and could be considered a bug. It's at least a documentation bug: `shows the timezone if the timezone does not match the current time-zone` – that is not completely true :). You could report this: https://git-scm.com/community