# Git: show dates in UTC

Tags: git, metadata, utc

The following command shows some metadata about the last git commit in json format:

```
git show --quiet HEAD --pretty=format:"{\"hash\":\"%h\", \"author\":\"%cn\", \"commit date\":\"%cd\"}"

{
  "hash":"0fc0fc0", 
  "author":"Adam Matan",
  "commit date":"Sun Jan 26 12:26:19 2014 +0200"}
}
```

Is there a way to present the date in the UTC/GMT time zone, e.g. `"Sun Jan 26 10:26:19 2014"` ?

Comment: UTC is a timezone, not a format. What exactly do you mean by UTC format in this case?

Comment: @CharlesBailey True, fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see an utc format in the [log data formats](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) (listed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651782/6309)).

The closest I get from your format is:

```
git config log.date local

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\git\>git show --quiet HEAD --pretty=format:"{\"hash\":\"%h\", \"author\":\"%cn\", \"commit date\":\"%cd\"}"
{"hash":"b594c97", "author":"Junio C Hamano", "commit date":"Thu Jan 23 10:00:28 2014 -0800"}

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\git\>git config log.date local

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\git\Documentation\technical>git show --quiet HEAD --pretty=format:"{\"hash\":\"%h\", \"author\":\"%cn\", \"commit date\":\"%cd\"}"
{"hash":"b594c97", "author":"Junio C Hamano", "commit date":"Thu Jan 23 19:00:28 2014"}
```

So from iso:

```
"Thu Jan 23 10:00:28 2014 -0800"
```

To local:

```
"Thu Jan 23 19:00:28 2014"
```

As commented, this is *not* UTC, unless the your machine local time is already UTC.

---

That was discussed on the [mailing list](https://public-inbox.org/git/CAEOYnAQYMrNAe9s1V-0DVLdL-B_KpHMDP5e=yRnbCkMWdrvFHQ@mail.gmail.com/T/#u):

> ### Adding `user.hideTimezone` for setting UTC timezone
>
> Authoring and sharing a commit by default exposes the user's time zone.
>
> "`commit --date=YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+0000`" suffices to put the author
> time in UTC but not the commit time in UTC.
> But the user shouldn't have to pass a flag at all.
>
> Git should entirely stop accessing, recording, and sharing the user's time zone, full stop.
>
> Failing that, git should by default stop accessing, recording, and sharing the user's time zone, but if individual users want to have their time zones on their commits, they can opt into it.

Junio C. Hamano, Git maintainer, answered:

> You are free to run
>
> ```
> $ TZ=GMT git commit
> ```
>
> if you wanted to opt out of the feature, but this has been the
> default since day one and people expect Git to behave this way.

Also:

> For now, using the `--date` argument on git commit allows you to also pass a timezone:
>
> ```
> git commit --date="$(TZ=PST date)"
> ```

This patch (for adding a  `user.hideTimezone`) is yet to be fully developed.

Comment: This isn't UTC unless your system is configured with the timezone set as UTC. How can this be the accepted answer?

Answer (score 47):

You can use this:

```
TZ=UTC0 git show --quiet --date=local --format="%cd"
```

If you want to control the date format, you can do this:

```
TZ=UTC0 git show --quiet --date='format-local:%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ' --format="%cd"
```

Update 2021-10-16: changed `TZ=UTC` to `TZ=UTC0` thanks to @alex-shpilkin.

Comment: That seems to work :-) A bit more readable: `TZ=UTC git show --quiet --date='format-local:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ' --format="%cd"`

Comment: Also `TZ=UTC git show --quiet --date=iso-local` if you’re happy with git’s ISO format (shorter format string).

Comment: Unfortunately this command is not portable: you can't run it as is on Windows and it will not work on other systems that don't recognize the `TZ` environment variable.

Comment: @dolmen Setting `TZ` to `UTC` is not even POSIX-compliant; Windows [does recognize the `TZ` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/tzset), but one should set it to the POSIX-mandated value `UTC0`. (I assume you mean this issue and not the fact that `cmd.exe` in Windows doesn’t support local variable assignments, because portability between `sh` and `cmd.exe` is basically impossible.)

Answer (score 4):

Technically git's Unix timestamp format (e.g. via `--date='unix'` / `--format='%at'`) is always in UTC too. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log / https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats for details.

Comment: As a complement, 'unix' will print raw timestamp like `1700125979`. Use `TZ=UTC date --date='@1700125979'` to convert it to `Thu Nov 16 09:12:59 AM UTC 2023`