# Display git log dates in a different non-UTC time zone

Tags: git

My local timezone is set to UTC, but occasionally I'd like to see `git log` commit dates adjusted from UTC to a different time zone. I've searched the man page for git log but I didn't see anything related to changing the displayed timezone, other than showing non-UTC dates in UTC. The normal use case seems to be to turn git commit timezones that are non-UTC into UTC, but I want to go the other way without modifying the system-wide timezone. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @Elogent, please see my edit. The question linked is related to removing the timezone offset to get to UTC, I'm trying to add an offset.

Comment: So, none of the linked answers (such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15103333/5044950)) are answers to your question?

Comment: I see, I was setting TZ incorrectly. That one works.