# Remove time and time zone of all git commits, but keep date

Tags: git, git-commit

I would like to remove the time and especially time zone information of all commits that have been created in a repository. Is that possible? And if not would it be possible to simply set the the time to `00:00` and time zone to `+0000`?
(I want to keep the date btw. It's just the time and timezone that I don't want.)

I have only found questions talking about [changing the author of all commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493936/could-i-change-my-name-and-surname-in-all-previous-commits), but nothing about just altering a property in all commits keeping the remaining information.

And yes I know there are other ways people could find out where I live etc, but this would be good enough for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Warning**: Editing any information of a commit will change its hash and,
consequently, the hash of all descendant commits, which may lead to
["rewriting" history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186549/10095231) if anyone else has already fetched the commit in
question.

---

As mentioned, [git filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) can be used to rewrite many commits at
once.

Editing only the timestamps can be accomplished with its
[environment filter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#git-filter-branch---env-filterltcommandgt):

> This filter may be used if you only need to modify the environment in which
>   the commit will be performed. Specifically, you might want to rewrite the
>   author/committer name/email/time environment variables (see
>   git-commit-tree for details).

Specifically, one can set the `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`
environment variables with values in the git [internal date format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree#_date_formats):

> It is <unix timestamp> <time zone offset>, where <unix
>   timestamp> is the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch. <time zone
>   offset> is a positive or negativeoffset from UTC. For example CET (which
>   is 1 hour ahead of UTC) is +0100.

**Warning**: The following code examples rewrite the entire tree at once.

They can be simply [changed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4494037/10095231) in the **env-filter**.

> I would like to remove the time and especially time zone information of all
>   commits that have been created in a repository.

To **remove** only the **timezone** information, one may just set the date
variables to `$timestamp +0000`:

```sh
git filter-branch --env-filter '
  GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$(git show -q --format="%at" "$GIT_COMMIT") +0000"
  GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git show -q --format="%ct" "$GIT_COMMIT") +0000"
  ' -- --all
```

> (I want to keep the date btw. It's just the time and timezone that I don't
>   want.)

To **remove** both the **time** and **timezone**, it is a little more tricky
(using the ISO 8601 [format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree#_date_formats)):

```sh
git filter-branch --env-filter '
  author_ts="$(git show -q --format="%at" "$GIT_COMMIT")"
  committer_ts="$(git show -q --format="%ct" "$GIT_COMMIT")"
  GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$(date -d "@$author_ts" +"%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00 +0000")"
  GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(date -d "@$committer_ts" +"%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00 +0000")"
  ' -- --all
```

**Note**: The timezone information does not appear in the [format example](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree#_date_formats),
so this might break in the future. So one could also [use the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15103333/10095231) `TZ`
environment variable to set the timezone, but I'm not sure how portable it is:

```sh
TZ=UTC git filter-branch --env-filter '
  author_ts="$(git show -q --format="%at" "$GIT_COMMIT")"
  committer_ts="$(git show -q --format="%ct" "$GIT_COMMIT")"
  GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$(date -d "@$author_ts" +"%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00")"
  GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(date -d "@$committer_ts" +"%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00")"
  ' -- --all
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! Unfortunately it only changed the time zones. The times themselves are still there. edit: Sorry I just realized that you literally mention that above the code.

Comment: You're welcome :). I managed to change the time aswell and added it to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can't "not store a time", but you can always set the time to 00:00 and the TZ to +0000.

For new commits, the most direct way would be to set the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` and `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` environment variables.  For example at a `bash` command line you could say

```
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(date +%Y-%m-%d) 00:00:00+0000"
export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$(date +%Y-%m-%d) 00:00:00+0000"
```

You'd want to make sure you do this before the first commit of each day; perhaps by adding it to your login scripts or something.

Your phrasing suggests you might also have a history of commits.  Those can be changed as well, e.g. by using `git filter-branch` with the `env-filter` option.  See the `filter-branch` docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch for details of how this works.

However, it's important to understand that this is a history rewrite - i.e. you would be replacing all existing commits with new commits, and if anyone else shares this repo, it would put them in a broken state requiring some recovery.  (See "recovering from upstream rebase" in the git rebase documentation for an understanding of what would be involved.)  There's no way around this really - the commit and author dates are an integral part of each commit.

Comment: A bit cleaner and without race condition:
`UTC_DAY_BEGIN=$(TZ=0 date +%F)T00:00:00+0000; export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$UTC_DAY_BEGIN; export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$UTC_DAY_BEGIN`
```

Comment: @ominug Why do you bleieve this makes a difference with respect to any "race condition"?

Comment: Extremely rare, but my code fetches the date only once, yours twice. The day could change between the fetches.

Comment: Even if I took that seriusly, it's not a race condition\.

Comment: I mean, if the day changes between the fetches, the both variables would differ. From that, anybody could deduce that the (shell rc) script has run at exactly 00:00. I think this is not in line with the desire described in the question of "removing time and especially time zone information". So while it is very rare, it is a bug (independent of whether you call it [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) or not).

Answer (score 0):

I never have to use that, but someone here creates a plugin to manage this situation. You can access the code here: https://github.com/bitriddler/git-change-date

Comment: Thanks, I tried the tool. It's buggy (it will apply incorrect time zones and times) and besides that it would take me hours to go through all the commits. :/