# Git config alias escaping

Tags: git, bash, escaping, git-alias

I'm trying to write a git alias that removes from the commit messages the string "[ci skip]" (placed at the end of the message), but I'm having problem with escaping. The alias takes all the commit from the one passed as argument to `HEAD`.

If I run the following command:

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter "sed -e \"s/\[ci skip\]$//g\"" master..HEAD
```

it works as expected. Anyway if I create the following alias:

```
unwip = !sh -c 'git filter-branch -f --msg-filter \"sed -e \\\"s/\[ci skip\]$//g\\\"\" $0..HEAD'
```

and I run `git unwip master` it complains about bad config, but I expect it to behave as the previous commads. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just guessing: Maybe also shield the backslash escaping the squarebrackets by additional escaped backslash like so `\\\[ci skip\\\]` ?

Comment: @Dilettant not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT This solution doesn't work in all cases. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39616600/1212203) is a correct solution which works in all cases.

I'm using `bash` as a command-line and the following alias worked for me:

```
unwip = "!f() { git filter-branch --msg-filter 'sed -e "s/[ci skip/]$/g"' $1..HEAD ; }; f"
```

The only downside is that you're specifying the interpreter and always using `sh`. In my case I'm relying on user's shell. Though I don't believe it will be a problem in any of major shells as we're doing just basic stuff.

Comment: This is an incorrect example - the `"` after `sed -e` actually *ends* the first quoted string. The coloured syntax highlighting demonstrates this. You're lucky that the `;` characters are inside a second quoted string, otherwise `git` would treat `;` as a comment character and ignore the rest of the line. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39616600/5353461) for a correct solution.

Answer (score 30):

**Generic solution**

Getting a `git` alias to pass the parser correctly can be a mind-boggling set of `\\\\"` noise, so I created two aliases:

```
# Quote / unquote a sh command, converting it to / from a git alias string
quote-string = "!read -r l; printf \\\"!; printf %s \"$l\" | sed 's/\\([\\\"]\\)/\\\\\\1/g'; printf \" #\\\"\\n\" #"
quote-string-undo = "!read -r l; printf %s \"$l\" | sed 's/\\\\\\([\\\"]\\)/\\1/g'; printf \"\\n\" #"
```

This allows you to convert anything you could type into `sh`<sup>+</sup>, eg:

```
$ echo '\"'
```

> `\"`

Into a quoted string fit for an alias:

```
$ git quote-string
echo '\"'
```

> `"!echo '\\\"' #"`

To quote a multi-line string, I wrote a longer [script](https://gist.github.com/HaleTom/61e2c94dc4d76b58c9f38fc8b6cec3ae), which I suggest you run as:

`git quote-string |`[`sponge`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)

**Answering OP's specific issue**

Using `git quote-string` on the OP's command, I get:

> `"!git filter-branch -f --msg-filter \"sed -e \\\"s/\\[ci skip\\]$//g\\\"\" master..HEAD #"`

So, to use the OP's preferred alias name, under `[alias]` in `~/.gitconfig`, add:

```
unwip = "!git filter-branch -f --msg-filter \"sed -e \\\"s/\\[ci skip\\]$//g\\\"\" master..HEAD #"
```

**Debugging**

Sometimes it's nice to see what is going on under the hood. Try this alias:

```
debug  = "!set -x; GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2 GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2 git"
```

Just insert `debug` between `git` and whatever would usually follow, eg for the OP's question:

`git debug unwip`

---

`+` `git` uses `/bin/sh` to execute aliases beginning with `!`<sup>*</sup>. To work around this, create a command line like: `bash -c 'echo \\\"'` and then pass this to `git quote-string`.

`*` See the "Debugging" heading for proof

Comment: Excellent!
One issue is when I run `git quote-string` [it outputs on multiple lines](https://gist.github.com/fadookie/7ae5cbec94245609165efee08da21c17).
Also you reference `git shell-quote` in your post, I presume you meant `quote-string`?

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the terminology and copy/pasted from my working `gitconfig` for `quote-string`. 

I also added a script for multi-line aliases. Talk in chat if you still have multi-line output issues?

Comment: it appears the new aliases you pasted in are identical to the old ones. [I set up a chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125033/discussion-between-eliot-and-tom-hale) but was unable to invite you for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

`git` is *suuuper* helpful and just reports this error for any issue:

```
fatal: bad config line 19 in file /home/you/.gitconfig
```

Have fun trying a gazillion combinations of quotes and escapes to figure it out!

Eventually I resorted to reading [the source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9e49351c3060e1fa6e0d2de64505b7becf157f28/config.c). Here's how it parses an alias:

```
alias = isspace* iskeychar+ spacetab* '=' value
isspace = ' ' | '\t' | '\v' | '\f' | '\r' (but not '\n')
spacetab = ' ' | '\t'
iskeychar = 'a'-'Z' | 'A'-'Z' | '0'-'9' | '-'
value = (quoted | unquoted)*
quoted = '"' not('\n')* '"'
unquoted = not('\n' | ';' | '#')*
```

Additionally:

1. A comment is started by a `;` or `#` outside of a quoted section and extends to the end of the line.
2. The following backslash escapes work: `\t`, `\n`, `\b`, `\"`, `\\`. They work exactly the same in quoted and unquoted sections. Other escape sequences cause an error.
3. You can also ignore a newline by putting `\` at the end of the line. Again this works exactly the same in quoted and unquoted sections.

Here's an example:

```
# !echo some ";"
    foo="!echo "some "\";\""
```

Of course, after all this I found it wasn't working because my key contained a `_`. What a git.