# Automatic documentation of gitconfig aliases using sed or awk

Tags: git, awk, sed, documentation-generation, git-config

I'm currently using the below code (hacked together) to generate documentation for my git aliases using 'git alias'. This assumes there is a comment above each alias starting with ### and the aliases are formatted as 'alias_name = command'. This works as is but does anyone have a more gooder method? :)

Current code (contents of `$HOME/.bin/bin/gdoc`):

```
grep --no-group-separator -A1 '###' "$HOME"/.gitconfig | awk 'END{if((NR%2))print p}!(NR%2){print$0p}{p=$0}' | sed -re 's/( =)(.*)(###)/:*/g' | awk -F* '{printf "\033[1;31m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $1, $2}' | sort
```

Example aliases:

```
### use difftool to view differences in file
dt = difftool

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters/39523506#39523506
### add and commit a file, arg1=file, arg2=commit_message
ac = "!cd -- \"${GIT_PREFIX:-.}\" && git add \"$1\" && git commit -m \"$2\" #"

### remove any files that are in gitignore from tracking
ig = "!git rm --cached `git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore` #"

### print out available aliases
alias = "!$HOME/.bin/bin/gdoc #"

### add a file to gitignore
ignore = "!([ ! -e .gitignore ] && touch .gitignore) | echo $1 >> .gitignore #"

### git rm files that have been deleted without using git
r = "!git ls-files -z --deleted | xargs -0 git rm #"

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057261/git-config-alias-escaping/39616600#39616600
### Quote a sh command, converting it to a git alias string
quote-string = "!read -r l; printf \\\"!; printf %s \"$l\" | sed 's/\\([\\\"]\\)/\\\\\\1/g'; printf \" #\\\"\\n\" #"
### Unquote a git alias command command, converting it to a sh command
quote-string-undo = "!read -r l; printf %s \"$l\" | sed 's/\\\\\\([\\\"]\\)/\\1/g'; printf \"\\n\" #"

### debug git aliases - 'git debug <alias>'
debug = "!set -x; GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2 GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2 git"
```

Current output:

```
ac:                         add and commit a file, arg1=file, arg2=commit_message
alias:                      print out available aliases
debug:                      debug git aliases - 'git debug <alias>'
dt:                         use difftool to view differences in file
ig:                         remove any files that are in gitignore from tracking
ignore:                     add a file to gitignore
quote-string-undo:          Unquote a git alias command command, converting it to a sh command
quote-string:               Quote a sh command, converting it to a git alias string
r:                          git rm files that have been deleted without using git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk 'a{print $1""c;a=0}/###/{$1="";c=$0;a=1}' "$HOME"/.gitconfig | sort
```

Using `awk`, `grep` and `sed` in the same pipe is mostly a sign that they are not used efficiently. Usually they can be replaced by a single `awk` command.

For nicely indented output you may use `column`:

```
awk 'a{print $1"%"c;a=0}/###/{$1="";c=$0;a=1}' "$HOME"/.gitconfig | sort | column -ts%
```

Note: I'm injecting a `%` separator with `awk` which is used to indent the output with `column`

Output:

```
ac                  add and commit a file, arg1=file, arg2=commit_message
alias               print out available aliases
debug               debug git aliases - 'git debug <alias>'
dt                  use difftool to view differences in file
ignore              add a file to gitignore
ig                  remove any files that are in gitignore from tracking
quote-string        Quote a sh command, converting it to a git alias string
quote-string-undo   Unquote a git alias command command, converting it to a sh command
r                   git rm files that have been deleted without using git
```

---

If you have `gawk` (GNU awk), you can also use just awk, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
in_alias{
    aliases[$1]=comment
    in_alias=0
    len=length($1)
    if(len > maxlen){
        maxlen = len
    }
}
/###/{
    $1=""
    comment=$0
    in_alias=1
}
END{
    n = asorti(aliases, sorted) # <-- Requires gawk
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i ++){
        pad = maxlen - length(sorted[i]) + 1
        printf "%s%"pad"s%s\n",sorted[i]," ",aliases[sorted[i]]
    }
}
```

Save that to a file at, let's say, */usr/local/bin/git-aliases* and make it executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/git-aliases
git-aliases "$HOME"/.gitconfig
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind explaining how the awk command works? I see the pattern search for ### but I don't really follow how 'a' and 'c' are being used.

Comment: `c` means _comment_, a variable which stores the comment text of the alias. `a` is a flag which can be `0` or `1` and indicates whether we are inside an _alias_ definition or not. This works only when the file is "properly" formatted, meaning alias commands start with a `###` followed by the alias definition in the next line.