# find git commits with no author

Tags: git, github

Through use of an import tool I have ended up with some git commits that have no author. For example here is a git log output showing an authorless commit and a normal commit

```
commit 40c2638378b33ac98a8d9570552ecd01e38174be
Merge: c2c068f 8f0c30c

    Merge libde265 (1.0.2-2) import into refs/heads/workingbranch

commit c2c068f30652fd3e63b55c509ae50828c98daa22
Author: Debian Multimedia Maintainers <pkg-multimedia-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Date:   Mon Jan 11 18:12:19 2016 +0000

     ffmpeg_2.9


     Gbp-Pq: Name ffmpeg_2.9.patch
```

github will not accept these commits. So I need to fix them up, to do that I need to find them.

How can I find such commits so that I can fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a soloution but it's a bit hacky.

```
git log > log1
git log --author "" > log2
diff -u log1 log2
```

---

For posterity the complete find and fix script (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28845565/5083516 for some hints on the fixup side)

```
 #!/bin/bash -ev
 rm -f loggood
 rm -f logall
 for TAG in $(git tag) ; do
     git log --pretty=format:"%H" --author="" $TAG >> loggood
     #git log doesn't seem to add a final newline, add one ourselves
     echo >> loggood
     git log --pretty=format:"%H" $TAG >> logall
     echo >> logall
 done

 LC_ALL=C cat loggood | sort | uniq | sponge loggood
 LC_ALL=C cat logall | sort | uniq | sponge logall
 LC_ALL=C comm -13 loggood logall > logbad

 for COMMIT in $(cat logbad) ; do
     git checkout $COMMIT
     git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit
     git replace $COMMIT $(git log --pretty=format:"%H" -n 1)
 done

 git filter-branch -f -- --all

 for COMMIT in $(cat logbad) ; do
     git replace -d $COMMIT
 done
```

Comment: You can do the same thing with `git rev-list`, which merely prints the commit IDs. However, given that the repository was created by an export/import tool, it might be simpler to re-export it with a corrected tool, or run it through `git-fast-import` with something that corrects these.

Answer (score 2):

You may utilize [`--pretty`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441010/the-shortest-possible-output-from-git-log-containing-author-and-date) format to output full commits line-by-line.

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"
```

Then from the output can check what commits have corresponding empty author (ie second column).

Comment: This will spit out all commits without an author:  git log --pretty="%aN END-AUTHOR %H" | grep '^ END-AUTHOR '