# How I can get distinct dates from my commits in the git history?

Tags: git

I need to record roughly how long I worked on a project so I need to extract the dates from my commits co I can give a rough calculation. So fart I filter my commits with the

```
git log --author="^name^" -- path ^folder_that_work_upon^
```

But how I can make the git to deisplay the distinct dates from my git commit history? For example I need to do a list like:

```
Nov 29
Nov 15
Nov 22
Nov 17
...
```

So to know how may days I worked upon.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853332/how-to-change-git-log-date-formats, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441010/the-shortest-possible-output-from-git-log-containing-author-and-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the output of `git log` to the desired format, and pipe the output into `sort` and `uniq`

```
git log --pretty=format:'%cd' --date=format:'%b %d' | sort | uniq
```

results in an output like

```
Nov 19
Nov 18
```

Answer (score -1):

You shold add these params below

```sh
--pretty=format:'%cd' --date=format:'%b %d'
```

Other date format you can read [How to change Git log date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853332/how-to-change-git-log-date-formats)