# How get list of files in specified directory with commit dates in Git?

Tags: git

The following command prints list of commits for specified directory:

```
git log  -- "C:\WORKDIR\REPOS\some_repo\some_folder"
```

How to get list of files in the same directory with commit date?
And to sort them by date or filename?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make git show a list of the files that are being tracked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606955/how-can-i-make-git-show-a-list-of-the-files-that-are-being-tracked)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648942/git-ls-files-with-date

Comment: There is no example how to apply directory filtering (-- "C:\WORKDIR\REPOS\some_repo\some_folder") with those commands.

Answer (score 2):

```
git ls-tree --name-only HEAD foldername/ | while read filename; do   echo "$(git log -1 --format="%cd " -- $filename) $filename"; done | sort -r
```

the same, but with recursive search in subfolders (can take some time)

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD foldername/ | while read filename; do   echo "$(git log -1 --format="%cd " -- $filename) $filename"; done | sort -r
```

Comment: I suggest changing format of the date from %cd to %ci as it sorts correctly, since %cd starts with weekday name.